# Encoding and Decoding text using a Cipher program

Tags: java, encryption

I'm trying to create a Cipher program for a project for college and I am able to create the cipher but I am unable to then encode it. My code is below, can someone steer me in the right direction? The first two methods are ok its mainly the last two methods I am having a problem with. This is my first semester doing any kind of programming so I am quite new to it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Cipher
{
public static void main (String[] args){
    System.out.print("Please type a sentence to be encrypted\n");
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = inputScanner.next();
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    char[] inputArray=input.toCharArray();
    inputScanner.close();

    char[] alphabetArray = {' ','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q'
            ,'r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
    char[] cipherArray = alphabetArray.clone();
    createCipher(cipherArray);
    encrypt(alphabetArray, inputArray, cipherArray);
    for(int index=0; index<alphabetArray.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.print(alphabetArray[index]);    
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    for(int index2=0; index2<cipherArray.length; index2++)
    {
        System.out.print(cipherArray[index2]);
    }
    System.out.print("\nYour encrypted message is:\n");
    for(int index3=0; index3<inputArray.length; index3++)
    {
        System.out.print(inputArray[index3]);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");
    decrypt(alphabetArray, inputArray, cipherArray);
    for(int index4=0;index4<inputArray.length; index4++)
    {
        System.out.print(inputArray[index4]);
    }

}
public static void createCipher( char[] alphabet )
{
    if (alphabet!=null)                                                
    {                                                                
        Random generator = new Random();
        for (int index=0; index<alphabet.length; index++ )
        {
            int otherIndex = generator.nextInt(alphabet.length);
            char temp = alphabet[index];
            alphabet[index] = alphabet[otherIndex];
            alphabet[otherIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
}

public static void encrypt(char[] alphabet, char[] input, char[] cipher)
{
    if(input!=null)
    {
        for(int index =0; index<input.length; index++)
        {
            for(int index2 =0; index2<alphabet.length; index2++)
            {
                if(input[index]==alphabet[index2])
                {
                    input[index]=cipher[index2];
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}

public static void decrypt(char[] alphabet, char[] encryptedInput, char[] cipher)
{
    if(encryptedInput!=null)
    {
        for(int index =0; index<encryptedInput.length; index++ )
        {
            for(int index2=0; index2<cipher.length; index2++)
            {
                if(encryptedInput[index]==cipher[index2])
                {
                    encryptedInput[index]=alphabet[index2];
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you know about `Map`s? You need to assign a random, unqiue, `Character` to each latin character in a `Map` and then use that `Map` to lookup the substitution.

Comment: No maps were never covered in the lectures, are they difficult to implement?

Comment: Maybe start with the [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html) then.

Comment: Maps are not hard to implement, and are very useful. Read the javadocs for the Map interface and the HashMap implementation. That is a good place to start

Comment: I looked at the javadocs and I am still none the wiser. I don't know how to implement them

Answer (score 1):

in this method

```
public static void encrypt(char[] alphabet, char[] input, char[] cipher)
{
    if(input!=null)
    {
        for(int index =0; index<input.length; index++)
        {
            for(int index2 =0; index2<alphabet.length; index2++)
            {
                if(input[index]==alphabet[index2])
                {
                    input[index]=cipher[index2];
                }
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

you need to type `return;` after the statement `input[index]=cipher[index2];` You should do the same in the decrypt() method. Then your program should be fine. Now, could you also execute the incorrect code by hand, and tell me why you needed a return statement?

Comment: You use the return statement to change the variables in a different method in this case the main method. Would I be right in saying this? Also, when I implemented the return statement, it doesn't encrypt the whole word/sentence, just the first letter

Comment: The normal way of saying thanks on stackoverflow is to hit the accept button at the left next to the answer (the greyed out V symbol).