# Encrypting a string using a cipher array

Tags: java, encryption

I was given the task of writing a program which converts plain text to cipher text using a randomly generated cypher of normal letters.
The cypher array has a different specific letter for each letter in the alphabet . e.g. the letter 'a' corresponds to 'x', 'b' to 'j' and so on. 
The plain text and cipher text were both stored as arrays.
 I am able to generate the cypher array but I can't seem to create an encrypted array using the plain text and cipher text arrays.
When I run this piece of code it generates the plain text code as the result of my encryption.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys might have

Here is my code thus far:

```
    String plaintextString = new String( plaintext ) ;
    plaintextString = plaintextString.toLowerCase();
    plaintext = plaintextString.toCharArray() ;

    char i =0 ;
    for (int index=0; index<plaintext.length; index++)
    {
        i = plaintext[index] ;
        if ( i == ' ')                      //The space character 
        {                                   //doesn't get encrypted
            plaintext[index] = ' ' ;
        }
        for (int index2=0; index2<alphabet.length; index2++)
        {
            if ( i == alphabet[index2])    //Alphabet array already generated
            {
                encrypt[index]= cipher[index2] ;                                    
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: [Homework night](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20923378/2071828)?

Comment: can you post all your code, or can you guarantee that the bug is in this piece of code?

Comment: Bug is definitely in this piece of code. Program just won't store any values I want in char[]encrypt array for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you generate (or obtain) the 'cipher' array, but it should simply map each ASCII character into a different ASCII character. This should include, according to the code in your question, mapping the Space character (and in fact, any other non-alphabetic character) into itself.

If this is not the case, then I suggest that you first construct such 'cipher' array from whatever "mapping object" you have. Once you make sure of that, your method should be very simple:

- Input: character arrays 'plaintext' and 'cipher'.
- Output: character array 'ciphertext'.

And the code:

```
for (int index=0; index<plaintext.length; index++)
    ciphertext[index] = cipher[plaintext[index]];
```